# adding on elements of a paired record to the original record (perhaps using a subselect?)

Tags: django, django-views

My data and model looks more or less like this:

```
      ID      NAME   STUFF    PAIRED_AGAINST
      1       john    xxx       3
      2       jane    yyy       4
      3       jill    zzz       1
      4       jake    aaa       2

class Swaps(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    stuff = models.CharField()
    paired_against = models.IntegerField()
```

I need help, I think with a subselect, that will return a queryset that gives
me:

```
id, name, stuff, paired_against, paired_against.name, paired_against.stuff
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **paired_against** the primary key for a different person? Then you should be using a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) instead of an integer field.

```
class Swaps(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    stuff = models.CharField()
    paired_against = models.ForeignKey(self, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Edit**

Thanks Daniel!

Comment: Should be `ForeignKey('self')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try. But one question first ... there are times where the entry is not paired against another entry. Can I have an entry of None as a default?

Comment: @Kevin sure, just set `null=True, blank=True`.